# Process doesn't terminate when closing

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a programm and have a problem with closing it. 
I added the following to listeners:

```
KeyListener kl = new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {     
            if(evt.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                shutdown();         
            }
     }
 };

WindowListener wl = new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
             shutdown();
          }
};

public void shutdown()
{
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
    //dispose of a buffer
}
```

I also set:

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

If I run the the programm in eclipse both listeners close the programm and terminate the process. However if I run it with the runnable .jar only the keylistener works correctly. Closing the window normally does close it, but the process isn't terminated. Why is this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try removing frame.dispose() . How are you starting the jframe? From main or from another process?

Comment: Removing frame.dipose() didn't help. I start the jframe in the construcutor of my gui class. And get a object of the gui class in main.

Comment: Try `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING))`. That should close it.